# C - Same mutex called in two different files, doesn't work well

Tags: c, mutex

I have a file1.c with: `pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` in global. And in file1.h : `extern pthread_mutex_t  mutex;`. But I also call this mutex in file2.c.

file1.c and file2.c uses mutexes like that:

file1.c:

```
#include "finc1.h"

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *f1()
{
   if (...)
   {
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      return (NULL);
   }
   if (...)
   {
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      return (...);
   }
   else
   {
      ...
   }
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   return (...);
}

void *f2()
{
   ...
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   return (...);
}

void *func1()
{
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   if (...)
     return (f1());
   if (...)
     return (f1());
   return (f2());
}
```

file1.h:

```
...
extern pthread_mutex_t mutex;
...
```

file2.c:

```
#include "finc1.h"

void func2()
{
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   ...
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

And I have another file, let's say file3.c with func3() on it, that don't have any mutex but call func1() then func2().

file3.c:

```
#include "finc1.h"

void func3()
{
   if(...)
     return(func1());
   func1();
   func2();
}
```

Now here is the problem. That mutexes only works 1 time over 10. And I don't know why. Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you mean by "it only works 1 time over 10."  What does "doesn't work" mean in the context of mutexes?

Comment: How are you deciding when the mutexes do or don't work?  Do you have a small but full example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I have an executable test (I don't know the code, but it have to work) that is testing multi-threading. And when I launch it, it said if it works or not, and it only works approximatively 1 time over 10.

Comment: Your problem statement is vague. But, one thing to check is to make sure `func1` and `func2` do not return early from the function without unlocking the mutex.

Comment: I don't know about pthread, but on windows mutexes are reentrant: waiting for a mutex in the same thread that locked it always succeeds and return immediately... since you are using the same mutex in 2 different functions called from the same thread, you may be in this same scenario.

Comment: @user315052 In this case, there must have been a infinite loop. I think.

Comment: @Elfayer: I can't comment, since you don't provide enough information for me to confirm or refute your statement.

Comment: If you are using Linux, consider changing the initializer to `PTHREAD_ERRORCHECK_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP` and see if you get any help from the threading library on potential misuses of the mutex.

Comment: @BradleyT.Hughes `error: ‘PTHREAD_ERRORCHECK_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP’ undeclared here (not in a function)`